# React MobX: Out of bounds read: 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Все с наступившим Новым годом!
Столкнулся со следующим вопросом, имею код со следующей структурой:
время от времени сталкиваюсь с ошибкой в консоли `[mobx] Out of bounds read: 0` в связи с чем таблица не отображается,
Просьба, подсказать, в связи с чем всплывает данная ошибка и как с ней бороться, возможно я не корректно написал структуру?
Заранее благодарен

History.js

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Context } from '..';
import DataTable from '../components/RegularTable'
import { observer } from 'mobx-react-lite';
import { fetchNumberHistory } from '../http/baseAPI';

const NumberHistory = observer(() => {
    const {table} = useContext(Context);

    useEffect(() => {
      fetchNumberHistory((rowsPerPage > table.numberHistory.count ? 0: page ),rowsPerPage).then(data => table.setNumberHistory(data))
},[page, rowsPerPage, table])

  return(
   <DataTable 
       data={table.numberHistory.results} 
       countRows={table.numberHistory.count}
       onPage={e => setPage(e)}
       rowsOnPage={e => setRowsPerPage(e)}
   />
   )
 })
```

Store.js

```
import { makeAutoObservable } from 'mobx'

export default class TableStore {
    constructor(){
        this._numberHistory = []
        makeAutoObservable(this)
    }
        setNumberHistory(history){
        this._numberHistory = history
    }
    get numberHistory(){
        return this._numberHistory
    }

}
```